# How to post local images to Facebook via JavaScript SDK without URL?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I am trying to use the JSSDK for a desktop website, not a mobile website. I am able to login, and then here is what I am doing:

1. Enable user to login with app_id, and get access_token.
2. Get a local image's base64 data (its a constraint) and turn that to a blob.
3. Send an upload request with this blob as image "source"
   So by the docs I am expected to get an "id" if successful, along with redirection to the post url.

Here's my snippet:

```
//2.
function base64ToBlob(base64String) {
    const parts = base64String.split(',');
    const header = parts[0];
    const encodedData = atob(parts[1]);
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(encodedData.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        buffer[i] = encodedData.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([buffer], { type: header.replace(/data:([^;]*);base64,/, '$1') });
}

//3.
async function handleUpload(accessToken, blob) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('source', blob);
    formData.append('access_token', accessToken);
    formData.append('caption', 'test_photo_upload');
    
    try {
         const response = await fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/me/photos', {
             method: 'POST',
             body: formData,
        });
    
        const data = await response.json();

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}, ${JSON.stringify(data.error)}`);
        console.log('Photo uploaded successfully:', data);
             return data;
        } catch (error) {
             console.error('Error uploading photo:', error);
             return null
        }
   }
```

It says the endpoint has deprecated due to the related permissions having been deprecated.

[image]

Comment: This _should_ not even be working with image URLs - not when you are sharing a page, that you don't even own. Facebook removed the general ability to overwrite the thumbnail for shared links a while ago; only the owner of the shared page should be able to make posts with a different thumbnail, than the one specified via the OG meta data, after _domain verification_.

Comment: And whether actual photo uploads to a user profile via API are still possible, I don't even know for sure right now. But if they are, then you would need to make the relevant POST request (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo#Creating) with a "file upload" yourself, the JS SDK does not come with a method to do that.

Comment: @CBroe I mentioned wikipedia url just as an example wrongly and I am not actually using it. With or without the *href* param, its still not working. 
Also, I did try by uploading a file myself, and it was succesfully uploaded and in return it gave me a media ID from which I could get a deeplink. But its only for mobile devices and cannot be reused for sharing the post directly. I did check out the request you gave but theres not much I could understand from the #Creating portion of the docs. Could you please give an example from that? Thanks!

Comment: You would need to make a `multipart/form-data` request. The file to upload can be passed under the parameter name `source` which Facebook historically used - or any other name. They basically just look for any file upload being contained in the request, the actual parameter name doesn't matter.

Comment: I have tried that and it returns a media id that is only allowed on mobiles browser and apps. I had edited my post for this, and I have provided my code again. Please advise..

Comment: According to the documentation, this endpoint should return a JSON with an `id` for the photo, and a `post_id`. Not sure how you get from that, to `https://fb.gg/me/media_asset/{id}`? A "photo" _is not_ the same thing, as a media asset. `facebook.com/id` should work (in that it redirects to the "real" URL of the photo post.)

Comment: Do I need to request extra permissions from the user for this? (in this case I am logging in with my developer account only) For now its just giving me an error "Something went wrong".

Comment: For the photo point: I am not a user of Facebook thats why some terminology gets past me, now I got it. Apparently I was confusing two different methods I was calling. The media_asset id was received from another endpoint. 

Secondly for the current code, I am getting "something went wrong" and the response I got was blank double ""

Comment: What part are you talking about now, _viewing_ the result, on Facebook, in your browser? No, viewing your own photos - of the user that you are logged in with - via the UI, should not require any permissions. Try and request the ID you got, via the API, and see what response that gets you. (`https://graph.facebook.com/{id_here}`)

Comment: @Cbroe due to a mistake on my part, I messed up the post with edits. can I start a  discussion and clarify as to the exact result I am getting and the exact code I am doing? I dont want this to be a chameleon post :(

Comment: A chat, you mean? Would probably make more sense if you cleared up the question. (Or deleted it, and then asked a new one.) A "messed up" question, were all the clarification happens in a chat, won't be of much value to future readers.

Comment: @CBroe cleared it up.

Comment: _"but there's no redirection"_ - not sure why you'd expect a redirect as API response? You should get an id, and a post_id. And making a POST request against either of those does not make much sense - if you want to request data about existing/created objects, it should be a GET.

Comment: @CBroe Wrong word choice, I meant by *visiting* that link graph.facebook.com/{id} in the browser should show the post page.. instead my brain took "redirect" from your 2nd-last comment, said this: "facebook.com/id should work (in that it redirects to the "real" URL of the photo post.)". The post request is such a silly mistake yes, on it.

Comment: The endpoint now says deprecated. I updated the post..

Comment: That's what I suspected, I just could not find it mentioned anywhere in the docs explicitly, what permission this would need.

Comment: I added this info and some official link about this change in the answer, I will just begin a new question. I hope they had clearly marked the change as deprecated..

Comment: @CBroe if you may here's a follow up question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77918330/how-to-post-local-images-to-facebook-via-javascript-sdk-v19-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the permission "publish_permission" and its dependent endpoints were stated to be deprecated long since 2018 and done for in 2020. Instead of continuing this question I will ask a new one for what the current method is.

Article for this deprecation: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/07/31/platform-update-publish-permission/

Here's a related answer on stack: [Facebook Graph API SDK v5 - Publishing a picture to a page's Album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958829/facebook-graph-api-sdk-v5-publishing-a-picture-to-a-pages-album)

The official docs should have stated this as deprecated. Instead we get this in the form of error message. Nvm.