# How to post local images to Facebook via JavaScript SDK (v19.0)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

My plan was to submit an image via formData to the /{album_id}/photos or /me/photos endpoints. But these have been deprecated. What is the latest allowed method for this?

Any ways where I am able to provide the image would be great. The facebook social-plugin buttons still work with page metadata, such as og:image but in this case it has to be a URL, not any uploads/formdata. Any workarounds would be appreciated.

This is a follow up question from here:
[How to post local images to Facebook via JavaScript SDK without URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77904490/how-to-post-local-images-to-facebook-via-javascript-sdk-without-url)

Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to upload photos to a user profile via API any more. Sharing a URL that has the image set as thumbnail is the only way to achieve something even remotely close, but for that you would have to actually store the uploaded image somewhere, because that needs the image to be available via HTTP again.

Comment: And how does it work on their end I mean will that image persist with Facebook, if say the initial upload is deleted?

Comment: Facebook re-scrapes shared URLs from time to time, so if the image is not available any more at some point, they _might_ keep the old one, or they _might_ simply show the shared URL without any image then, and show title and description only.

Comment: any link to their policies regarding such?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/faq#faq_1131343433556264 - it should keep the existing image inside an already shared post, unless that post attachment was explicitly refreshed. (If user B shares the URL from the post that user A made earlier though, then the share on B's wall will likely not contain the proper image, if the image URL does not exist any more by then.)